# python pandas OLS.predict, what is the correct signature?

Tags: python, model, pandas, regression, predict

I am having a pandas OLS model,

```
mid_lag_lead_df_model
```

> -------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------
>
> Formula: Y ~ <1> + <2> + <3> +
>
> Number of Observations:         56
>   Number of Degrees of Freedom:   4
>
> R-squared:         0.2864
>   Adj R-squared:     0.2452
>
> Rmse:              0.0001
>
> F-stat (3, 52):     6.9554, p-value:     0.0005
>
> Degrees of Freedom: model 3, resid 52
>
> -----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
>
> ```
>  Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>         1     0.0527     0.0268       1.97     0.0547     0.0001     0.1053
>         2    -0.0009     0.0269      -0.03     0.9730    -0.0537     0.0519
>         3     0.0980     0.0268       3.66     0.0006     0.0455     0.1505
> intercept     0.0000     0.0000       1.59     0.1184    -0.0000     0.0000
> ```
>
> ---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------

If i need to predict, the `y` value from `[0.000207, -0.000361, -0.000091]`

```
mid_lag_lead_df_model.predict
```

what the signature should be using `predict` as above?

Comment: what I also found later is using `mid_lag_lead_df_model.predict` by passing in a DataFrame same format as the one passed in the pandas OLS model for the `x` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to calculate `y` this your independent variables vector:

```
mid_lag_lead_df_model.beta.dot(pandas.Series([0.000207, -0.000361, -0.000091]))
```

Comment: 2015, this is still the only method I was able to use to get an OOS prediction out of pandas.ols